# How to stream from iTunes(on iMac) to iphone/ipad on same network, at the same time?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios, ipad, imac

I can use the Remote app to control what is currently playing on the iMac, but is there a way to stream the audio so that it is playing out through the iMac AND the ipad/phone in parallel?

Comment: Please explain the downvotes so I can either delete or modify the question

Answer (score 3):

Rogue Amoeba's [Airfoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) can stream to multiple computers and iOS devices (using a free iOS app). It can stream from iTunes, or from many other applications.

Answer (score -1):

Go for Home Sharing. Its the only and the best way provided by Apple. Google out for how to setup it.

Comment: This adds nothing that hasn't already been said, yet in even less detail.

Answer (score -2):

Home sharing will let you access and play your Mac's music library from your iPad. However, there's no provision for synchronously playing the same track on the Mac and the iPad.

Answer (score -2):

Yeah, just use home sharing, here you could get the tips: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4557

Comment: Home sharing enables you to play your iMac music on your iPhone or iPad.  But this is not what the user is asking for, he asks for the music the be played **simultaneously** on the iMac and the iPhone/iPad.